# cookies are not working, I can't obtain cookies from localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, jwt

So I am making a user validation system for my application, but I can´t validate a token if I can´t obtain it from the cookies in my browser. The thing is the cookies don´t seem to be appearing there.

```
import { getConnection } from '../database/connection.js';
import createAccessToken from '../libs/jwt.js';
import { queriesUsers } from '../database/queries.js';
import { serialize } from 'cookie';

export const loginController = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body; 

        const pool = await getConnection(); 
        const result = await pool
            .request()
            .input("username", username) 
            .input("password", password) 
            .query(queriesUsers.validateUser);
  
        const user = result.recordset[0]; 

      if (user && user.Type === 'S') {
        const token = createAccessToken(user);
        if (token) {
          console.log(token)
          res.cookie("Token", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 600000,
          });
          console.log("cookies", req.cookies);
          res.status(200).json({token});
        } else {
          res.status(500).json({ error: "Error"});
        }
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'Credenciales inválidas' });
      }
  
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error al validar el usuario:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Error al validar el usuario" });
    }
  };
```

This is my log in controller (for more context, this application does not have a register controller only a log in controller). When I console log the cookies I just obtain this anwer:

```
cookies [Object: null prototype] {}
```

[This is how it looks in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvwzL.png)
Does anyone know why aren´t the cookies appearing on my browser? If you need to see more of my code just let me know.

Here is the frontend that executes the controller:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import styles from '../styles/login.module.css';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext'; 

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { login } = useContext(AuthContext); 

  const handleUsernameChange = (event) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
  };

  const handlePasswordChange = (event) => {
    setPassword(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      await login(username, password);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        setError('Error al iniciar sesión. Verifica tus credenciales.');
      } else {
        setError('Error de conexión. Inténtalo nuevamente más tarde.');
      }
    }

    setPassword('');
    setUsername('');
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.main}>
        <div className={styles.descriptionContainer}>
          <img className={styles.logo} src="/biconlogo - copia.png" alt="bicon" />
          <h2 className={styles.subtitle}>¡Bienvenido!</h2>
          <p className={`${styles.descriptionText} ${styles.paragraph}`}>
            <b>BiCon Survey</b> es una solución que permite a los colaboradores
            identificar las actividades que se realizan y asignarles un peso que
            refleje la intensidad con la que ejecutan. La información recabada
            será de utilidad para el Modelo de Costeo Basado en Actividades.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.login}>
          <h2 className={styles.loginH2}>Iniciar sesión</h2>
          {error && <p className={styles.error}>{error}</p>}
          <form className={styles.loginForm} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
              <label className={styles.loginLabel} htmlFor="username">
                Usuario:
              </label>  
              <input
                className={styles.loginInput}
                value={username}
                onChange={handleUsernameChange}
              />
            </div>

            <div>
              <label className={styles.loginLabel} htmlFor="password">
                Contraseña:
              </label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className={styles.loginInput}
                value={password}
                onChange={handlePasswordChange}
              />
            </div>

            <button type="submit" className={styles.loginButton}>
              Iniciar sesión
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

And here is the user context (AuthContext):

```
import { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const useAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useAuth must be within AuthProvider");
  }
  return context;
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null); 
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

  const login = async (username, password) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      });

      const authToken = response.data.token;
      console.log(authToken)

      setUser({ ...response.data.user, token: authToken });
      setToken(authToken); 
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
      setErrors([]);
    } catch (error) {
      setErrors(error.response.data);
    }
  }

  const logout = () => {
    setUser(null); 
    setToken(null);
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    setErrors([]);
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{
      user,
      token,
      isAuthenticated,
      errors,
      login,
      logout,
    }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: This log in controller is on port 4000? i.e. is this code part of the server code that serves both the web pages(html/css/js) and handles the login API?

Comment: This is only the backend, the node server is running on port 4000, the frontend on the other hand is running on 3000. But I want to get the token from the backend not the frontend so I dont know if that could possibly be the problem

Comment: OK, can you show the front end code you use to call *THIS* backend

Comment: Sure! I just added the frontend to my question so you can see it there.

Comment: OK, so it's a cross site request, you need to allow credentials in the request for the browser to accept the cookie - not sure how that's done in axios, but I'm sure it's documented - look for anything to do with credentials regarding cross-site requests

Comment: Ok Ill try that thanks!

Comment: It worked thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

In the axios request add withCredentials: true :

```
const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      }, {
        withCredentials: true, 
      });
```

on the app add cors configuration like this:

```
// Use cors
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true, // Enable credentials (cookies)
}));
```